# How to serve Static and Media files in Azure blob with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload my assets to Azure blob, in my local it's working. `collectstatic` saving the static files in Azure blob only. But when i'm running via gunicorn it's saving in my local. I didn't add any configuration for static and media in nginx.

**nginx configuration:**

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name x.x.x.x:8000;


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_pass http://unix/home/myproject/project.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're running via gunicorn in your local too ??

Comment: NGINX is only responsible for serving your files. It has nothing to do with save. If it's not getting saved in right location then the issue is in your config or settings

Comment: in nginx only this kind of config will go `location /static {
        root /home/<username>/<project>/static;
    }` and same for media. That's it for `static` and `media` files

Comment: @xxbinxx no, i'm not using gunicorn in local. When i run with python, save and retrieve is working fine and it's saving in azure blob. But with gunicorn only this problem comes. I used that location config, when i saved the assets in local.

Answer (score -1):

As I known, for the `proxy_pass` directive of module `ngx_http_proxy_module`, there are two types of URL path can be specified, a domain name or IP address url path, else or a UNIX-domain socket path, as below.

[image]

I see you were using a UNIX-domain socket path, but it seems not to be correct. Please refer to the related doc of [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) directive to try to correct it and make it works.

Comment: `proxy_pass` is working fine, there is no problem with application server. Can you read my question. The problem is with nginx+azure blob to serve static and media files.